# Recommended number of database roles SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Does anybody know what the recommended number of database roles is on a SQL Server 2008 R2 Database.

I have a database (That i have inherited) that has 130 database roles... I know this is causing users on the floor issues, so I was wondering what the recommendation would be, what a maximum would be.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of roles almost has no limitation. But role is supposedly to make database security management easier, too many of it certainly is not making management and maintenance easier.